# Why is "window.top.location" working in iframes?

Tags: javascript, iframe

If I can insert iframes in a forum comment, example:

```
<iframe src="http://badwebsite.comm/xss.html"></iframe>
```

cat `xss.html`

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
        window.top.location = "http://badwebsite.comm/stolecred.html";
    </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

So when anyone enters this forum, it will be redirected to `http://badwebsite.comm/stolecred.html/`.

From this point, the `stolecred.html` can be an exact copy of the login page for the original forum.

After the user gave his credentials, the `http://badwebsite.comm/stolecred.html` can redirect it to the original website.

**Question**: 
So allowing `iframe`s in a forum is a very big security problem? It shouldn't be allowed in any manner? Why does a modern browser allow `window.top.location` to work in an `iframe`?

Comment: Because that is how frames/iframes work and in modern browsers you can prevent it with sandboxing the frames.

Comment: "sandboxing the frames" - and this needs to be done by the forum admin?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox

Comment: If the forum software allows HTML to be injected into the actual page markup, I think there might be a security issue.

Comment: `top.location` is write-only from iframes, i don't see a specific risk, other than "frame-busting"

Comment: Can someone post their answer as answer? :) So this is a very big security issue, users can be tricked to give their user/password. In general, only when the iframe is sandboxed by the forum admin should be iframe allowed. Yes?

Answer (score 0):

There is <del>no</del> limited risk (as long as there isn't a bug in the browser).

If you run the example below, you'll get the following error message in the JavaScript console of your browser:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with URL '[Why is "window.top.location" working in iframes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34518065/why-is-window-top-location-working-in-iframes)' from frame with URL 'http://schneidr.de/misc/bad_redirect.html'. The frame attempting navigation of the top-level window is sandboxed, but the 'allow-top-navigation' flag is not set.

<sup>(Error message from Chrome, wording may be different in other browsers)</sup>

```html
<iframe src="http://schneidr.de/misc/bad_redirect.html"></iframe>
```

The reason for the error is, that the browser doesn't trust JavaScript that is embedded via a frame **from a different domain**. Because of this it is automatically sandboxed.

To allow the JavaScript changes in an iframe you need to set the `sandbox=""` attribute, for this example to `sandbox="allow-top-navigation"`. So, if you allow iframes in comments you should at least filter this attribute before saving and displaying it.

If you do this it is pretty safe to allow iframes from a security point of view. Personally I wouldn't allow it on a site I administer because I have no control over the content displayed via the iframe, which could bring me legal trouble.

Comment: but this is working, the website will be redirected to the badwebsite! it doesn't matter which webbrowser I try

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I only get said error message in the console (Tested in: Chrome 47, Firefox 43, Internet Explorer 11, Edge)